# Extracting color values from polygons drawn in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have drawn polygons around Solar Panel units in California in google earth engine. I am interested in extracting the individual color values of the Red, Green and Blue bands within these polygons.

Anyone know how to do this?

I am thinking it is a relatively simple task but I am not sure where to look for these color values.

Comment: Hello MadiWit, which product are you using? You'll need to check which bands contain the color values for the specific product. Also, what exactly do you mean with extracting? Do you want to have 1 average value for R, G and B for each polygon? Could you show what you have tried so far to achieve what you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean extract values from the underlying Google Base map, you can't.  There's no way to do analysis on those images.  If you happen to be working on images in the US, you could try to extract the values (using reduceRegions) from the NAIP imagery in the Data Catalog, but the alignment might be a little off compared to what you drew.